# How to Use ipadx and ipady in Entry Widget in .place() Geometry Method in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
entry1 = Entry(root ,bg='#121212', fg= '#E2E2E2', font=("Product Sans Bold", 14) ,width= 13, insertwidth=1, insertbackground='#B7B7B7',bd=0)

entry.place(x=350, y=200)

# entry1.pack(ipady=6, ipadx=20)

entry1.insert(0, " ")
```

I can't use ipadx and ipady in .place() Geometry Method. How to Do That?

Comment: I guess u can use `height` and `width` for ur purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ipadx` and `ipady` with `place`, those aren't supported options.

[The valid options](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm) for `place` are: `anchor`, `bordermode`, `height`, `in_`, `relheight`, `relwidth`, `relx`, `rely`, `width`, `x`, and `y`.

Comment: what could be a possible solution?

Comment: @MianAffan: it's unclear what the problem is. What problem are you trying to solve? Your question simply asks how to use a feature that isn't supported. By definition you can't, since it's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has a solution.
In `place()` enter *height* or *width* as a keyword with an integer, that will fix your problem.

**Example**:

```
Button(root,text="Button").place(x=0,y=0,height=70,width=140)
```